# Finding related entities from three list

Tags: python, list

I have three lists that contain the following data:

```
Entities:  ['Ashraf', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Kabul']
Relations:  ['Born', 'President', 'employee', 'Capital', 'Located', 'Lecturer', 'University']
sentence_list: ['Ashraf','Born', 'in', 'Kabul', '.' 'Ashraf', 'is', 'the', 'president', 'of', 'Afghanistan', '.', ...]
```

As the `sentence_list` is a list of sentences. In each sentence, I want to check if any word of `Entities` and `Relations`, the combination of specific words should be added in another list. such as, (`Ashraf, born, Kabul`) in the first sentence.

What I did:

First incomplete Solution:

```
# read file
with open('../data/parse.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    json_data = json.load(myfile)

for i in range(len(json_data)): # the dataset was in json format
     if json_data[i]['word'] in relation(json_data)[0]: # I extract the relations
         print(json_data[i]['word'])
     if json_data[i]['word'] in entities(json_data)[0]:
         print(json[i]['word'])
```

The output: `(Ashraf, Born, Ashraf)`, where I want `(Ashraf, Born, Kabul)`

The next incomplete solution: I stored `json_data` to a list and then I did this:

```
json_data2 = []
for i in range(len(json_data)):
    json2_data.append(json_data[i]['word'])
print(json_data2)


'''
Now I tried if I can find any element of `Entities` list and `Relations` list
in each sentence of `sentence_list`. And then it should store matched 
entities and relations based on sentence to a list. '''

for line in json_data2:
    for rel in relation(obj):
        for ent in entities(obj):
            match = re.findall(rel,  line['word'])
            if match:
                print('word matched relations: %s ==> word: %s' % (rel,  line['address']))
            match2 = re.findall(ent, line['word'])
            if match2:
                print('word matched entities: %s ==> word: %s' % (ent,  line['address']))
```

Unfortunately, does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
to_match = set(Entities+Relations)
l = [{j for j in to_match if j in i} 
        for i in ' '.join(sentence_list).split('.')[:-1]]
```

**Output**

```
[{'Ashraf', 'Born', 'Kabul'}, {'Afghanistan', 'Ashraf'}]
```

---

Note that I'm, returning a list of `sets` to avoid duplicate values, given that for instance in `Entities` `Afghanistan` appears twice.

Useful reads:

- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [sets — Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)
- [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html)

Comment: Thank you, but in the second or more index of the list, it takes repeated elements from  `Entities list`. As you defined each sentence by `.split('.')` but it should select from both `'Entities and Relations'` based on its existence in the `sentence-list`. How to fix that?

Comment: last week, the solution you proposed work for me, now it returns an empty list, I don't why?